# Can I do some some action before app will be updated?

Tags: android

I would like to do some clean action in my application before it will be updated from Goole Play. Eg. delete some files from previous app version.
There's any way to do this in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do this at the time your app starts for the first time after update? Looks a lot easier. Just store last updated app version in user preferences or in a file and verify it every time app starts.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API call for this, or any unofficial method either. However, you could have your app check a file on a server everytime it runs. You could store the latest version code in that and check it against the installed app's version code. If the version code is higher, then there is an update available. You can then do your clean up operation, and  prompt the user to update the app. However, sometimes users don't update apps, so you should make sure that either the data being cleaned up is non-essential to functionality, or you force users to update the app by not letting them get past the update prompt until they have updated it.